# Creating a Python class method using a closure

Tags: python, closures, class-method

I'm using the `unittest` module for the first time (as I'm pretty new to Python), and I find myself performing the same test assertions over and over again. I want to pull that code out into a common function, but the `unittest` assertions are methods of `TestCase` (i.e. `self.assertTrue`). I'm trying to use a closure to construct class methods in each `TestCase` that perform the assertions for me. For example:

```
def _keys_in_dict_asserter(cls):
    """
    A simple closure that creates an "assert keys in dict" function for each TestCase
    """

    def cls_asserter(dictionary, *args):

        for key in args:
           cls.assertTrue(key in dictionary)

    return cls_asserter

class TestFunctionUnderTest(TestCase):

    # I want to create an asserter function as a class method using this
    # class object. Python won't let me. Why?
    @classmethod   
    keys_in_dict = _keys_in_dict_asserter(cls)  

    def test_returned_dict_contains_expected_items(self):
        """
        Make sure the dict returned has all the keys expected by the caller under normal operation
        """

        keys_in_dict(function_under_test())
```

I'm not sure how to write this correctly, though. Help?

Comment: How about a simple private method? Or a simple function that gets `self` passed as an argument?

Comment: Yeah, why not just make it a method? If the function name does not start with "test", it won't be interpreted as one.

Comment: I started with that approach, but every Test class would need its own copy of the method. And it can't be implemented outside one of those classes because it has to use `self` in order to call the `assert*()` methods. Maybe I can create a dummy class that inherits from TestCase just to expose that method?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense... `keys_in_dict = _keys_in_dict_asserter(cls)` where does `cls` come from? I don't really see why you can't just do: `@classmethod;def keys_in_dict(cls, dictionary, *args): ...` without the wrapper `_keys_in_dict_asserter`

Comment: Why not just inherit `TestCase`, add `keys_in_dict_asserter` in the subclass as a method and inherit your tests from that subclass instead?

Comment: @Eswcvlad that's what I finally did to work around my problem: I created `ExtendedTestCase` with `keys_in_dict()`, then inherited from that with all my test case classes. It's not an answer to my question of how a class method can be created using a closure, so I'll leave the question unanswered for now. Thanks for the suggestion.